# CORS with POSTMAN

Tags: http, cors, postman

This subject has been asked a couple of time, but I still don't understand something:

When I read answers about

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

issue, it says a setting should be set on the requested server in order to allow cross domain: `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';`.

But, please tell me why when asking from **postman** (which is a client), It's working like a charm and I have a response from the requested server?

Thank you

Comment: Postman doesn't care about SOP, it a dev tool not a browser.

Comment: @Musa Ok, so if it's a browser (client) issue, why should I have to modify something on the server?

Comment: Its the server that tells the browser that its okay([CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)) or not for a given site to access its content and the browser honours it

Comment: The real question here is how to configure POSTMAN to mimic the browser behavior where an ORIGIN request is sent first. In essence how to you make POSTMAN behave like a browser because we need to test to make sure our APIs are configure correctly.
So what if the API works from POSTMAN and it breaks due to CORS from the browser. It means the API is useless.

Comment: @ChrisLove did you figure something out?

Comment: No, I never did

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As @Musa comments it, it seems that the reason is that:

> Postman doesn't care about SOP, it's a dev tool not a browser

By the way here's a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) in order to make it work on your browser (this one is for chrome, but you can find either for FF or Safari).

Check [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) if you want to learn more about **Cross-Origin** and why it's working for extensions.

Comment: Then how do I protect my API routes being accessed from tools like Postman? For example, an API which requires a captcha verification. But if directly accessed from Postman, the captcha verification is bypassed

Comment: The same question, besides this, how can an extension makes breaking the single origin policy?

Comment: Sadman Muhib Samyo, CORS is not there to protect the server. It is there to protect the client from cookie stealing and other client side attacks.

Comment: @SatyanRaina then, why do we allow all origins from the server? How can a configuration in the server, affect client-side protection?

Comment: @Rationalist Think about warnings on a product. The producer attaches a "4+ yrs" warning on a toy. It can save a life if the client obeys it by using the product in a proper context.
The rules defined by the server can save the visitor's data as their browser obeys the rules, preventing a script from a foreign page accessing the API from the user's machine.

Comment: @DarkWingDuck yes thanks, I started understanding more after some time. It makes sense, but this time we rely on the browser's producer right? Can the browser not be compromised? Do you know any such issues from history?

Answer (score 136):

[`CORS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) and `SOP` (Same-Origin Policy) are server-side configurations that **clients decide to enforce or not**.

Related to clients

- Most **Browsers** *do enforce* it to prevent issues related to [`CSRF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attack.
- Most **Development tools** *don't care* about it.

Comment: CORS does not prevent CSRF attacks, but CSRF tokens do

Comment: You can produce CORS error from Postman as well if you send 'Origin' as header key and any other origin (example : https://google.com) as header value. This will remove dependency on UI to debug this issue.

Answer (score 68):

If you use a website and you fill out a form to submit information (your social security number for example) you want to be sure that the information is being sent to the site you think it's being sent to.  So browsers were built to say, by default, 'Do not send information to a domain other than the domain being visited).

Eventually that became too limiting but the default idea still remains in browsers.  Don't let the web page send information to a different domain.  But this is all browser checking.  Chrome and firefox, etc have built in code that says 'before send this request, we're going to check that the destination matches the page being visited'.

Postman (or CURL on the cmd line) doesn't have those built in checks.  You're manually interacting with a site so you have full control over what you're sending.

Comment: More accurately postman does not send a XmlHttp Request that would get checked but a top level network call (like your opening the URL on a new browser tab) so it does not get kicked in even when in extention

Comment: The browser are not checking that your site isn't sending data to another domain : if the other domain site is allowing all origins, your browser is 100% ok with that. It's the opposite, it's protecting the other domain, in case your site would use its resources without being authorized.

Answer (score 37):

While all of the answers here are a really good explanation of what cors is but the direct answer to your question would be because of the following differences postman and browser.

Browser: Sends `OPTIONS` call to check the server type and getting the headers before sending any new request to the API endpoint. Where it checks for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Taking this into account `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header just specifies which all CROSS ORIGINS are allowed, although by default browser will only allow the same origin.

Postman: Sends direct `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` etc. request without checking what type of server is and getting the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` by using `OPTIONS` call to the server.

Comment: "Sends OPTIONS call to check the server type and getting the headers before sending any new request to the API endpoint" — That isn't true. It only does that for non-simple requests.

Comment: @Quentin can u elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, Postman used for debugging and used in the development phase. But in case you want to block it even from postman try this.

```
    const referrer_domain = "[enter-the-domain-name-of-the-referrer]"
    //check for the referrer domain
    app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
      if(req.headers.referer.indexOf(referrer_domain) == -1){
        res.send('Invalid Request')
      }

      next();
    });
```

Comment: add the code in your file with the router. If you have a file with "routers", add the code at the top of the file. The same file where you have: 
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

Comment: edit it in `app.js` if you use `node app.js` to run the server.

Comment: can that protect your server from ddos?

Answer (score 1):

Practically if someone is using POSTMAN to test an API implementation that uses CORS they are going to want to understand what to DO to test various scenarios.

There are lots of explanations but no practical answers.

The Answer: Just create a Header attribute called "Origin" and set the value to whatever url domain you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I upvoted because it got me unstuck.  As with any voodoo, I wanted to know WHY is worked..and found this.  Here is a fuller explanation: 

https://zguyun.com/blog/how-to-test-cors-with-postman/

Step 2: Configure Request Headers
In the request settings, locate the "Headers" section. Add a new header with the key "Origin" and the value as your front-end domain. This simulates the Origin header sent by the browser during a cross-origin request.