# CORS issue doesn't occur when using POSTMAN

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cors, postman

I have been using POSTMAN for sometime now for sending `HTTP requests like GET, POST, PUT` for RESTful Webservices. Recently came across a situation, when sending a request to my REST API through browser, I got a message that

> No Access Control Allow Origin Header is present on the Requested resource.

The solution was ofcourse to add such an header to the API. 
However strangely, When I sent the the same request through POSTMAN I was able to get back the response.

So I want to know how is sending a request through POSTMAN different from sending a request through browser.

I went through this question: [CORS with POSTMAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250615/cors-with-postman), but it really doesn't provide an answer in detail.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**From [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) in Chrome Develop Extensions documentation:**

> Regular web pages can use the [**XMLHttpRequest**](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the [**same origin policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions.

Basically browser extensions have more privileges than web content. In the case of Chrome extensions, there is an option to enable cross-origin access.

Comment: So, this behavior for extension is assuming that Cross Site requests are enabled from server side. What happens if server itself is blocking cross site requests?

Comment: @Vrishank You would have to figure out how the server in question is desciding to block the request. Perhaps you need to add a referer header.