# HttpClient not getting response when POST

Tags: json, angular, http, post

I want to receive response from server. With Postman works great:
Request:

```
{
    "name": "antonio",
    "username": "antonio",
    "email": "antonio@antonio.pl",
    "password": "antonio"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "User was successfully registered"
}
```

Im trying to implement same thing in Angular, so I got:

```
  this.http.post('http://localhost:8090/api/auth/signup',
  JSON.stringify({name: name, username: username, password: password, email: email}),
  {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})})
  .subscribe(res => alert(res[0]));
```

Checked backend API, works great but alert still is not appearing. Any ideas?

Comment: This is Angular 6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS issue doesn't occur when using POSTMAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554013/cors-issue-doesnt-occur-when-using-postman)

Comment: Nope, mine issue is different.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to JSON.stringify() the request if you are sending it as 'application/json'. I don't know how your backend interprets it.

```js
this.http.post('http://localhost:8090/api/auth/signup',
  {name: name, username: username, password: password, email: email},
  {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})})
  .subscribe(res => alert(res[0]));
```

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post

Comment: That's true, but also got something like: need to add alert('smth) after http.post, because It wont send request

Comment: it should sent the post when you subscribe to it
maybe try `let signup = this.http.post(...); ` 
then `signup.subscribe(...`

Comment: also, are you using HttpClient: angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient or just Http: angular.io/api/http/Http )

Comment: you should really be using a service containing the observable, Inject it into your Component and subscribe to it there