# Angular 4 HttpClient adding authorization Header

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am trying to access an API which requires Basic Authorization.

Using Postman or Advanced Rest API Tool, I am able to get the response. However when I'm trying to access through Angular 4 HttpClient I am getting this exception:

> login:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://someUrl.com:4400/api/v1/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Here is the angular code

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('api') private api) {

    }
    login(post) {

        let auth="Basic "+ btoa(post.username + ":" + post.password);
        console.log(auth);
         let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
         .set("authorization", auth);
       console.log(headers);
        return this.http.post(this.api + 'login',null,{
        headers:headers
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your api allow cross origin requests? try same origin and see what response you get paste the headers and response here. If possible allow cross origin request and then see repsonse as well.

Comment: Yes. cross origin is enabled. I am getting response if I am accessing the api via postman

Comment: Here is the request header
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:hosturl.com:3443
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Referer:http://localhost:4200/login
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36

Comment: I don't think Postman cares about CORS headers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36486188/398606), so you probably need to double check your CORS config on the server.