# Typescript (ionic app) - Basic auth not working

Tags: angular, typescript, http, ionic-framework, basic-authentication

Here is my code :

```
onClick() {
console.log("I am running...");

let headers: Headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa("Userid:password") );
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.get(this.url, options)
  .map((response: Response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }).subscribe();
}
```

I am getting error :
401 (Unauthorized)

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Kindly provide me some solutions.

Comment: Its a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue.. you have to setup appropriate headers in the server side. Also is this ionic serve?

Comment: I am getting response in postman after setting username and password but getting error here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250615/cors-with-postman

Answer (score 0):

It is a CORS issue. Make sure to have this header on your side AND on the server side too:

```
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
```

(Of course you can specify what you want to allow, the line above is just allowing everything for you)

Comment: why am i not getting unauthorized error when running in postman but getting error while executing application?

Comment: because there is no cross-origin request there, I assume :) in postman all such requests work fine but not in the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your API has CORS setup. Your API needs a options method for CORS preflight check. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request.