# Add CORS header to response in Angular 6

Tags: angular, rest, cors, http-headers, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to fetch some data from a backend server in Angular 6 so I can visualize it in my own way. I've already prepared a working GET request that results in a proper response with all the data I need, but the problem is that when it's used in a typical way, e.g in "normal" browser, I'm getting the CORS error - header is missing. So how do I get the data even with this problem? Typically, you must allow it on the server side, but this situation is a bit different. I've installed a Chrome plugin to add the header to every request. With the plugin, the CORS problem is no more.

So my question is, how (and if) can I add the CORS header in my Angular code to the response, so I wouldn't have to use any plugins and the app would work on every browser?

Also, just to prevent any comments, all the data I'm getting I have legal access to, they're my own and I'm just learning new stuff in Angular. As far as I know, I should use interceptors, but I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong. Here's my code:

The http service method:

```
  getFullResponse(domain: string, projectName: string, credentials: Credentials) {
    console.log('RequestService method getIssuesForProject() fired');

    return this.http.get('https://' + domain + '.myserver.local/api/' + projectName,
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(credentials.username + ':' + credentials.password)}),
        observe: 'response'
      }
    );
  }
```

The Interceptor class I wrote:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      map(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          event = event.clone({
            headers: event.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
          });
        }
        return event;
      })
    );
  }

}
```

This is the component.ts class:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {RequestService} from '../../shared/service/RequestService.service';
import {Credentials} from '../../shared/model/credentials';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project',
  templateUrl: './project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project.component.css']
})
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {

  projectKey = '';
  headers;
  credentials: Credentials;

  constructor(private reqService: RequestService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(domainName: string, projectKey: string, user: string, password: string) {
    this.projectKey = projectKey;
    this.credentials = {
      username: user,
      password: password
    };
    this.reqService.getFullResponse(domainName, projectKey, this.credentials)
      .subscribe(resp => {
        const keys = resp.headers.keys();
        this.headers = keys.map(key => `${key}: ${resp.headers.get(key)}`);
      });
  }

}
```

I've tried to use the Interceptor the way under this [link](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8), using the app.module.ts. This totally broke my app because I'm getting the CORS error even with the CORS plugin turned on. The other examples of code I found over the internet used code like

```
return next.handle(reqClone) 
       .map(event => { 
         if (event instanceof HttpResponse) { 
           event = event.clone({ 
             headers: event.headers.set('x-test-res', 'res-test-header') 
           }); 
         } 
         return event; 
});
```

in the interceptor, but I'm guessing it's for older versions of Angular, I can't use the `map` method this way, so I tried using it inside of `pipe` like it was used in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http). There's still something I'm missing though.

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt work like that. Cors is somehing that is handled serverside. Where the Serveradministrator sets those headers and allows certain domains. You should propably look into [JsonP](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_jsonp.asp) or if you have like you said control over the data look into allowing your domain on your server. Those are the [Acces Control Allow Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers)

Comment: I know what CORS is and how it works, but I'm asking if I can achieve the same effect with Angular as the Chrome plugin that still allows me to see the data just by adding the header.

Comment: This similar post may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250615/cors-with-postman

Comment: yes, it is. so for now it looks like there's no way to do this with Angular, because I have to modify the behavior of web browser which cannot be done by a web application...

Comment: @Jack_Russell The browser is responsible for restricting web apps from accessing cross-origin servers. Only by installing a plugin you can change this behavior. Web apps aren't allowed to change that, because if the could, there would be no point in having CORS.

Answer (score 0):

When you include certain headers like **Authorization** in your cross origin http request made to the server, browsers would generally make an **OPTIONS**(**pre flight**) request to the server asking for allowed **Access-Control-Allow-Methods** and allowed **Access-Control-Allow-Headers**, Your Server side code should respond with these for the browser to actually make your intended http request

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set Headers for the request. In order to avoid the **CORS error** in Angular you should use **proxy pass** configuration for development purpose.

add a file named **proxy.conf.json** near the **package.json**. from your Request get URL add **/proxy**

```
 this.http.get('/proxy/api/' + 
  projectName).subscribe(resData => {
        console.log(resData);
  });
```

In the **proxy.conf.json** set the proxy rule as

```
{
  "/proxy/*": {
  "target": "http://backendDomain:8080",
  "secure": false,
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "pathRewrite": {
  "^/proxy": "/"
  }
 }
}
```

change the serve command with little modification:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --port 55055 --host 0.0.0.0
```

Now the request to the backend will be originated from the same from angular domain and there will be no more **CORS** error

**Note** : This Proxy configuration in only for the development purpose. For the production environment You should configure in the webservers.

Comment: problem is, the address where the REST API is located, is a remote one. I've also tried to proxy the request via Nginx, but I'm totally new to this. As Postman request works, I wonder if there is a way to send the request from my app as if it was a Postman request, but something is not right here and right now I'm totally lost