# Path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint from Blazor, but works in Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, blazor

Have an Identity user database API with IdentityServer4 and a Blazor client in separate projects. I'm able to register a new user via Postman.
When running the code below in the Blazor client (for tinkering and learning)

```
@page "/registrer"
@using Models
@using System.Net.Http
@using IdentityModel.Client
@inject HttpClient Http

    <EditForm Model="@registerUserModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />

        <InputText id="email" type="email" @bind-Value="@registerUserModel.Email" />
        <InputText id="password" type="password" @bind-Value="@registerUserModel.Password" />
        <InputText id="confirmPassword" type="password" @bind-Value="@registerUserModel.ConfirmPassword" />

        <button type="submit">Registrer deg</button>
    </EditForm>

@code {
    private RegisterUserModel registerUserModel = new RegisterUserModel();

    public async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        var newUser = new RegisterUserModel
        {
            Email = registerUserModel.Email,
            Password = registerUserModel.Password,
            ConfirmPassword = registerUserModel.ConfirmPassword
        };

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var response = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = "https://localhost:5001/connect/token",

            ClientId = "client",
            ClientSecret = "511536EF-F270-4058-80CA-1C89C192F69A",
            Scope = "api1"
        });

        Http.SetBearerToken(response.AccessToken);

        await Http.PostJsonAsync("https://localhost:5001/register", newUser);
    }
}
```

I am able to get the access token and validate the Blazor client, but then I get this error

> dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.CorsPolicyProvider[0]
>         CORS request made for path: /register from origin: http://localhost:60013 but was ignored because path was not for an
>   allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint

Why? When it works in Postman and there is no CORS policy. Have tried to allow the client with `AllowedCorsOrigins`, just to check.

### Answer

Browser security prevents a webpage from making requests to a different domain than the one that served the webpage. This restriction is called the same-origin policy. The same-origin policy prevents a malicious site from reading sensitive data from another site. To make requests from the browser to an endpoint with a different origin, the endpoint must enable cross-origin resource sharing (CORS).

And it's not a good idea to store client secrets in an SPA or mobile app as every user is able to see and manipulate all code.

Comment: How you `AllowedCorsOrigins` ? Show the code of IdentityServer ConfigureService

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have configured a CORS policy in your ConfigureServices method on your IS4 API, something like this:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
        });
```

Also make sure you add your policy in the Configure method:

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Comment: Thank you, but why does it work in Postman and not from Blazor?

Comment: Well, a simple answer would be that Postman is a dev tool, not a browser. You can find a discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250615/cors-with-postman.

Comment: You're right, now it works and I also know why @LucaBNW

Comment: I missed this part app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

Comment: Allowing `any` origin is not really a good idea. It completely circumvents the purpose of the SOP.