# Postman Strange 401s

Tags: rest, postman

I am trying to use the PostMan client to hit a REST API. Using the client, I get a 401. If I take the exact same information and use the PostMan Chrome Extension, I get a 200. Reading the forums, someone mentioned that the REST API needs to have CORS enabled (because PostMan is basically a webapp), but I am a little confused as to how I would do that. On the server side, I have the ability to plug in allowed CORS domains, but if it is coming from my local machine, it doesn't have a domain, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS with POSTMAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250615/cors-with-postman)

Comment: @MickaelB. I appreciate the answer, but I already saw that article. Do you have any idea why the Chrome Extension would work, but the Fat Client would not?

Comment: The server is on localhost ? Have you a session cookie set on postman ?

Comment: Server is local. I am using an HTTP Header to authenticate.