# API get request working in postman but in jquery ajax getting blocked by CORS policy

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, api, cors

#### ERROR IN AJAX REQUEST

http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

#### MY CODE

```js
var srv_url = 'https://api-domain.com/api/index.php?type=join&meetingID=test01&moderatorPW=mp&fullName=John';
    var auth_token = 'e6a83f2844c9cdd4729b69dc851f96c1c073a23b4f37eb7cdec83bf8c9c7a06d'

    $.ajax({
      url: srv_url,
      type: 'get',
      beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth_token);
      },
      success: function(res){
        console.log(res)
      },
      error: function(e){
        console.log(e)
      }
    })
```

#### BUT WORKING IN POSTMAN

[image]

> If there are CORS related problems, why this request working in
>   postman in the same machine. Please help me, am I doing something
>   wrong in my ajax code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow cross origin access at server side using :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

You will find more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers)

Comment: Okay. But how it working it in postman without allowing it.

Comment: Did this work? I thought post 1.5 JQuery did this automatically.

Comment: @SumanBiswas because `Postman doesn't care about SOP, it's a dev tool not a browser`  [more details...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250615/cors-with-postman)

Comment: @ParitoshMahale Thank you for helping me. Currently, I have no access to backend.