# How to fix this issue Access-Control-Allow-Origin in angular axios request?

Tags: angular, axios

```
axios.get(this.apiURL, {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("Sucess");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
```

I get these issues, If you are experiencing this, Please help me.
Issues are followings

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://price-broadcaster-backend.dev.gke.papers.tech/api/observations/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: This should be handle from `Backend API`

Comment: I think so, but this api is working using postman

Comment: Yes It is working on Postman. But CORS should be handled from BE. and Nothing to do from FE side with Angular.

Comment: Postman handles requests differently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250615/cors-with-postman You need to set up the headers in your backend. This question has really nothing to do with angular or axios. It's all about the backend.