# Problem using fetch to retrive data from an API - works in Postman

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am trying to access an API using JavaScript. When accessing it using Postman everything works fine. I can make a GET request and it sends back the correct data. However when I try to do the same using `fetch()`, it either returns nothing or gives me an error (depending on the mode I am using).

```
<script>
    async function get_page() {
        const response = await fetch("MY_LINK", {
            method:'GET',
            mode:'cors',
            redirect:'follow'
            });
            return response;
        }
    get_page().then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err));
</script>
```

The above throws:

> Access to fetch at 'MY_LINK' from origin 'null' has been blocked by
> CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the
> request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

If I change the mode to `no-cors`, I get a reply but cannot seem to find the returned message (the body attribute is null) in it, that I am seeing when I use Postman.

Comment: works in postman but not in browser - yes, you're right, because that's how CORS works - the server needs to allow the browser to access the response - change the **server** to do so - as for no-cors, you now know what an opaque response is ... i.e. no information can be seen

Comment: @Bravo how is it possible that Postman is still able of giving the correct response (just wondering)?

Comment: I think this subject answers your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250615/cors-with-postman

Comment: because POSTMAN isn't a browser

Answer (score -3):

In a browser, with your function, this worked:

```
get_page().then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Full code (poke api :)

```js
async function get_page() {
        const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto', {
            method:'GET',
            mode:'cors',
            redirect:'follow'
            });
            return response;
}
        
get_page().then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Note about CORS:

Tested on the browser console while visiting:

- https://pokeapi.co/ -> ok
- https://developer.mozilla.org -> FAIL (Content Security Policy)
- https://www.google.com/ -> ok

so it pays to see your server code as well

This is the result of my code:
[image]