# cdk http api cors configuration not working

Tags: cors, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-http-api

I have this code which creates an http api, but the cors configuration is not working even though it shows up correctly in the console after deployment. I can still send a request from postman and execute the lambda behind the api, which shouldn't happen considering this cors configuration.

```js
const someApiDomain = new apigateway.DomainName(this, 'mydomain', {
  domainName: 'api.example.com',
  endpointType: apigateway.EndpointType.REGIONAL,
  certificate: someCert
})

const httpApi = new apigateway.HttpApi(this, 'my-api', {
  apiName: `my-api`,
  createDefaultStage: true,
  disableExecuteApiEndpoint: true,
  defaultDomainMapping: {
    domainName: someApiDomain
  },
  corsPreflight: {
    allowHeaders: [
      'Content-Type',
      'X-Amz-Date'
    ],
    allowMethods: [
      apigateway.CorsHttpMethod.OPTIONS,
      apigateway.CorsHttpMethod.POST,
    ],
    allowCredentials: false,
    allowOrigins: ['https://example.com']
  },
});

httpApi.addRoutes({
  methods: [apigateway.HttpMethod.POST],
  path: '/myapi',
  integration: new apigatewayintegrations.LambdaProxyIntegration({
    handler: myFunction,
  }),
});

new route53.ARecord(this, 'myapirecord', {
  zone: someHostedZone,
  recordName: 'api.example.com',
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(
    new route53targets.ApiGatewayv2DomainProperties(someApiDomain.regionalDomainName, someApiDomain.regionalHostedZoneId)
  ),
});
```

Is the route53 record bypassing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.  CORS checks are always carried out by browsers, but tools like Postman and curl [do not make CORS checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250615/cors-with-postman).

The CDK's ApiGatewayV2 `HttpApi` Construct supports [access control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-apigatewayv2-authorizers-readme.html#http-apis).  The ApiGateway `RestApi` has [broader auth capabilities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-apigateway-readme.html), including API Keys.