# get CORS problem when ty to get a token in keycloak with vuejs and axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, keycloak

I trying to access one keycloak with axios in my vuejs app, but I receive the cors error, can someone help me please? (If I make a post from POSTMAN to my keycloak works fine)

I using this code:

```
 const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append("grant_type", "password");
  params.append("client_id", "notas-front");
  params.append("username", usuario.value);
  params.append("password", password.value);
  console.log(params);
  const config = {
    //  withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
  };
  axios.defaults.headers.common["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] =
    "http://localhost:8080";
  axios
    .post(
      "http://localhost:8082/auth/realms/lumera/protocol/openid-connect/token",
      params,
      config
    )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

and get this error:
[image]

but when I look the request I can't find the error:
the OPTIONS returns 200
[image]

but the POST dont
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Postman [doesn't care](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250615/cors-with-postman) about Same Origin Policy, browser do. That's why your request is working in Postman but not in the browser.

[Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) is a response header, you can't set it on the client request. And as you can see from the OPTIONS response headers your server is returning: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080`

In a development environment the best way to solve this is setting a [proxy](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy) in your vue configuration. Otherwise you should configure the server to allow requests from `localhost:8080`

Answer (score 0):

Configure `Web Origins` properly in the Keycloak `notas-front` client config.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same problem after migrating from Vue 2.7 to Vue 3.1 which meant that we also had to make changes to sentry.ts and keycloak.ts.

But in sentry.ts we used `tracingOrigins: ["localhost", /^\//, /^https?:\/\//]`, which also applied to keycloak requests, hence came the CORS error.

We fixed it by using `tracingOrigins: [window.location.origin]`.