# How to prevent other origins except of 'specific origins' in Core Policy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-6.0

Why can I send request with all URLs to my API project, however inside my Program.cs I set only two specific URLs as allowed origins.

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy(name: "policyName", builder =>
  {
      builder.WithOrigins(

        "http://sitehere.com",
        "http://TheOtherSiteHere.com"

      );
    });
  });



app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("policyName");
```

In all of my controllers I have the `[EnableCors("policyName")]`'s attribute as well.

But in postman, with my local IP address or another computer's ip address which is in the same local network, all requests will be accepted.

In my case, I want to prevent all requests, except `"http://sitehere.com"` and `"http://TheOtherSiteHere.com"`

Comment: it's because Postman does not send 'Origin' header which is used for this purpose.

Comment: So what if an illegal person gets our API URL and send request via postman ?! isn't it a security issue then ? @Meysam

Comment: it's a Forbidden header name which means can not be modified programmatically.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name

Comment: So you mean the above code is fine ?

Comment: Yes. also check this question out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250615/cors-with-postman