# Why does "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, axios, cors

access to xmlhttprequest at 'http://teamdev.shop/questions/write' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by cors policy: response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: no 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I requested to post the data through axios and got an error as follows. What should I do in this situation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250615/cors-with-postman

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS carefully.