# Why does not postman encounter CORS issue , but web app does?

Tags: cors, postman, cross-domain

When I use postman for testing our api then I get results. But when I use my web project application then I get CORS error :

```
datatable = table.DataTable({
            'ajax': {
                "type": "GET",
                "url": "https://mat.cloud/api/clients",
                "crossOrigin": true,
                "headers": {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'x-api-key': "E2D67E37CE221593E5DAE5713713AD2D34CA4EAABE52443FE9016B82BE7ADAD2",
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJjbG91ZC5tdWx0aW1pY3JvIiwiaWF0IjoxNjk1MjA5Mzg2LCJzdWIiOiJNTUMgVG9rZW4gZm9yIGJhY2tlbmQiLCJpc3MiOiJNTUMiLCJleHAiOjE2OTc4MDEzODZ9.NUlzAM-8tGsiV9iSd1iSBBZp74B_zKY_09oAb5KsIMwbt0TWTBfkAqSF18mxuK3c0zFueavD_34xSnejQ-gFwg'
                },
                "dataType": "json"
            },
            'columns': [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "code" },
                { "data": "nom", "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "prenom", "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "adresse", "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "ville", "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "telephone", "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "email", "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "nationalite", "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "qualite", "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "mmcTypeClient.libelle", "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "mmcSegmentClient.libelle", "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": "pmsPrescripteur.libelle", "defaultContent": "" },
                { "data": null }
            ],
            .....

@Stateless
@Path("clients")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ClientService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ClientService.class);
    @Inject
    ClientDao customerDao;
    .....
    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAll() {
        List<TMmcClient> customer = customerDao.getAll();
        if (customer.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
        return Response.ok(customer, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();       
    }
    ....
```

So why ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS with POSTMAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250615/cors-with-postman)